# Rotating an object with quaternion

Tags: opengl, rotation, quaternions, glm-math

I have a question in regards to using quaternions for the rotation of my graphics object.

I have a `Transform` class which has the following constructor with default parameters:

```
Transform(const glm::vec3& pos = glm::vec3(0.0), const glm::quat& rot = glm::quat(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    const glm::vec3& scale = glm::vec3(1.0))
{
    m_pos = pos;
    m_rot = rot;
    m_scale = scale;
}
```

In my `Transform` class calculate the `MVP` as follows:

```
glm::mat4 Transform::GetModelMatrix() const
{
    glm::mat4 translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0), m_pos);
    glm::mat4 rotate = glm::mat4_cast(m_rot);
    glm::mat4 scale = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0), m_scale);

    return translate * rotate * scale;
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I use `const glm::quat& rot = glm::quat(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` my object appears normal on screen. The following image shows it:
[image]

However if I try to use for example `const glm::quat& rot = glm::quat(glm::radians(90.0f), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)` (rotating on y axis by 90 degrees) my object appears as if it has been scaled. The following image shows it:
[image]

I can't figure out what is causing it to become like this when I try to rotate it. Am I missing something important?

If it's of any relevance, the following is how I calculate my view matrix:

```
glm::mat4 Camera::GetView() const
{
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(m_pos, m_pos + m_forward, m_up);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: glm does not have a quaternion constructor specifying angle and axis. YOu are directly initializing the quaternion fileds with your values, resulting in some weird un-normalized quaternion.

Comment: @derhass how should I got about initializing it then?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can init a glm::quat using:

```
glm::vec3 angles(degToRad(rotx), degToRad(roty), degToRad(rotz));
glm::quat rotation(angles);
```

Where `rotx`, `roty`, `rotz` are the rotation angles around x, y and z axis and degToRad converts angles to radians. Therefore for your case:

```
glm::vec3 angles(degToRad(0), degToRad(90), degToRad(0));
glm::quat rotation(angles);
```

Regards